# How to specify a width in pod2usage?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have a small perl module, and am using Getopt::Long, and I figured I might as well use Pod::Usage to get a nice looking help display.

After some fiddling, I got it to work reasonably well, with one minor exception.  I can't set the width of the output.

My terminal is 191 characters wide.  Using perldoc Module.pm, it correctly formats the documentation to that width.  Using pod2usage(), it uses the default width of 76 characters.

I can't figure out how to get the width option passed in to the formatter.  The documentation shows how to set a different formatter (such as Pod::Text::Termcap) using a BEGIN block, and I used Term::ReadKey to pull the width (verified), but I just can't get the formatter to see it.

Any hints?

Here's the full module I'm trying to test, along with a small test script to load it.  To see what I mean, open a terminal that has a reasonable width (132 or more, so it's obvious), and compare the output of "./test.pl --man" with the output of "perldoc MUD::Config".

I can live without the man page style headers and footers that perldoc adds, but I would like it to respect (and use) the terminal width.

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use MUD::Config;
#use MUD::Logging;

my $config = new MUD::Config @ARGV;
#my $logger = new MUD::Logging $config;

#$bootlog->info("Logging initialized");
#$bootlog->info("Program exiting");
```

and MUD/Config.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

package MUD::Config;

=pod

=head1 NAME

MUD::Config --  Configuration options for PocketMUD

=head1 SYNOPSIS

./PocketMUD [OPTIONS]

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 8

=item B<--dbname>

Specifiy the name of the database used by PocketMUD S<(default B<pocketmud>)>.

=item B<--dbhost>

Specify the IP address used to connect to the database S<(default B<localhost>)>.

=item B<--dbport>

Specify the port number used to connect to the database S<(default B<5432>)>.

=item B<--dbuser>

Specify the username used to connect to the database S<(default B<quixadhal>)>.

=item B<--dbpass>

Specify the password used to connect to the database S<(default B<password>)>.

=item B<--dsn>

The DSN is the full connection string used to connect to the database.  It includes the
values listed above, as well as several other options specific to the database used.

S<(default B<DBI:Pg:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host;port=$db_port;sslmode=prefer;options=--autocommit=on>)>

=item B<--logfile>

Specify the text file used for debugging/logging output S<(default B</home/quixadhal/PocketMUD/debug-server.log>)>.

=item B<--port>

Specify the port used for player connections S<(default B<4444>)>.

=item B<--help>

Display usage information for PocketmUD.

=item B<--man>

Display full documentation of configuration module details.

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

PocketMUD is a perl re-implementation of SocketMUD.

It is meant to be a barebones MUD server, written in perl,
which can be easily modified and extended.

=head1 METHODS

=cut

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw( GetOptionsFromArray );
use Config::IniFiles;
use Data::Dumper;

BEGIN {
    use Term::ReadKey;

    my ($width, $height, $pixel_width, $pixel_height) = GetTerminalSize();
    #print "WIDTH: $width\n";
    $Pod::Usage::Formatter = 'Pod::Text::Termcap';
    $Pod::Usage::width = $width;
}

use Pod::Usage;
use Pod::Find qw(pod_where);

Getopt::Long::Configure('prefix_pattern=(?:--|-)?');    # Make dashes optional for arguments

=pod

B<new( @ARGV )> (constructor)

Create a new configuration class.  You should only need ONE instance of this
class, under normal circumstances.

Parameters passed in are usually the command line's B<@ARGV> array.  Options that
can be specified are listed in the B<OPTIONS> section, above.

Returns: configuration data object.

=cut


sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my @args = @_;
    my ($db_name, $db_host, $db_port, $db_user, $db_pass, $DSN);
    my ($logfile, $port);
    my $HOME = $ENV{HOME} || ".";

    # Order matters... First we check the global config file, then the local one...
    foreach my $cfgfile ( "/etc/pocketmud.ini", "$HOME/.pocketmud.ini", "./pocketmud.ini" ) {
        next if !-e $cfgfile;
        my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file  => "$cfgfile", -handle_trailing_comment => 1, -nocase => 1, -fallback => 'GENERAL', -default => 'GENERAL' );
        $db_name = $cfg->val('database', 'name')        if $cfg->exists('database', 'name');
        $db_host = $cfg->val('database', 'host')        if $cfg->exists('database', 'host');
        $db_port = $cfg->val('database', 'port')        if $cfg->exists('database', 'port');
        $db_user = $cfg->val('database', 'user')        if $cfg->exists('database', 'user');
        $db_pass = $cfg->val('database', 'password')    if $cfg->exists('database', 'password');
        $DSN = $cfg->val('database', 'dsn')             if $cfg->exists('database', 'dsn');
        $logfile = $cfg->val('general', 'logfile')      if $cfg->exists('general', 'logfile');
        $port = $cfg->val('general', 'port')            if $cfg->exists('general', 'port');
    }

    # Then we check arguments from the constructor
    GetOptionsFromArray( \@args ,
        'dbname:s'      => \$db_name,
        'dbhost:s'      => \$db_host,
        'dbport:i'      => \$db_port,
        'dbuser:s'      => \$db_user,
        'dbpass:s'      => \$db_pass,
        'dsn:s'         => \$DSN,
        'logfile:s'     => \$logfile,
        'port:i'        => \$port,
        'help|?'        => sub { pod2usage( -input => pod_where( {-inc => 1}, __PACKAGE__), -exitval => 1 ); },
        'man'           => sub { pod2usage( -input => pod_where( {-inc => 1}, __PACKAGE__), -exitval => 2, -verbose => 2 ); },
    );

    # Finally, we fall back to hard-coded defaults
    $db_name = 'pocketmud'  if !defined $db_name and !defined $DSN;
    $db_host = 'localhost'  if !defined $db_host and !defined $DSN;
    $db_port = 5432         if !defined $db_port and !defined $DSN;
    $db_user = 'quixadhal'  if !defined $db_user;
    $db_pass = 'password'   if !defined $db_pass;
    $logfile = '/home/quixadhal/PocketMUD/debug-server.log' if !defined $logfile;
    $port    = 4444         if !defined $port;

    $DSN = "DBI:Pg:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host;port=$db_port;sslmode=prefer;options=--autocommit=on" if !defined $DSN and defined $db_name and defined $db_host and defined $db_port;

    die "Either a valid DSN or a valid database name, host, and port MUST exist in configuration data" if !defined $DSN;
    die "A valid database username MUST exist in configuration data" if !defined $db_user;
    die "A valid database password MUST exist in configuration data" if !defined $db_pass;
    die "A valid logfile MUST be defined in configuration data" if !defined $logfile;
    die "A valid port MUST be defined in configuration data" if !defined $port;


    my $self = {
        DB_NAME => $db_name,
        DB_HOST => $db_host,
        DB_PORT => $db_port,
        DB_USER => $db_user,
        DB_PASS => $db_pass,
        DSN     => $DSN,
        LOGFILE => $logfile,
        PORT    => $port,
    };

    bless $self, $class;
    print Dumper($self);
    return $self;
}

sub dsn {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{DSN} = shift;
    }
    return $self->{DSN};
}

sub db_user {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{DB_USER} = shift;
    }
    return $self->{DB_USER};
}

sub db_pass {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{DB_PASS} = shift;
    }
    return $self->{DB_PASS};
}

sub logfile {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{LOGFILE} = shift;
    }
    return $self->{LOGFILE};
}

sub port {
    my $self = shift;
    if ( @_ ) {
        $self->{PORT} = shift;
    }
    return $self->{PORT};
}

1;
```

Comment: One is probably me not remembering to use Getopt::Long qw( GetOptionsFromArray ); Since I cut and pasted the relevant details to avoid posting a large file with extra cruft.

Comment: Ok.  I'll post the full module and a small test script that uses it.  pod::find was needed to keep the usage docs in the config module, rather than at the top level.

Answer (score 3):

Man, I was really looking for a challenge in this one...

I peeked at the code for `Pod::Usage` to see what's going on. `Pod::Usage` uses the `perldoc` command directly, so it would seem both `perldoc` and `pod2usage` would print the same way. In fact, on my system, both `perldoc` and `pod2usage` default more or less to 80 columns. I don't know why it's different on your system.

There is one exception:

If you set the `-noperldoc` argument, it will use `Pod::Text` for formatting, and `Pod::Text` has an option `-width => $width` when you create a new `Pod::Text` object.

I thought I might be able to pass an *undocumented* `-width` parameter to `pod2usage` and it would get passed to the `$parser` object which gets created. This object is a `Pod::Usage` object, but `Pod::Usage` is a subclass of `Pod::Text`.

No dice.

The options are passed as part of a separate `USAGE_OPT` options, so `$opt_width` is not set correctly. There's no *functional* interface for `Pod::Text`, so width is associated with a particular `$parser` object and not with the package in general. You can't set `$Pod::Text::width` and override the default `76` value. That's hardcoded in the program by default.

There is a way to use `Pod::Text`, find a way to grab the terminal width, pass that to your `Pod::Text` object, and then use that object calling the `parse_from_file` to method on your source file.

It would be a lot of work just so you can see your POD output at 130 characters wide if the terminal is 130 characters wide.

Comment: What's even stranger is if I call "perldoc MUD::Config" on the command line, at an interactive bash prompt, it displays the documentation as a proper man page... following the correct terminal width and using boldface as I'd expect.<p> However, making the same call inside perl using backticks, gets me the 76 column plaintext I don't want.

Comment: @Quixadhal `pod2usage` ends up using Perldoc which looks like it used Pod::Man, and then uses `nroff` to actually produce the layout. If something is formatting the page to 60 characters wide, it would be `nroff`. For example, you can use `pod2man | troff -man | less` which is what `perldoc` actually does. The `-man` is really the `an` formatting macro `nroff` will use. This is where the page width would be specified. You're talking about 1970s page formatting technology here. I have no idea how these various macros work.

Comment: I'm familiar with nroff (and troff), and I can tell you that nroff can (and should) respect your terminal size.  This is why most systems kept man pages in nroff format, rather than running catman to pre-render them, as the pre-rendered versions would be fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

It's unsurprising that the comments in response to this question have expressed differing opinions as to how many columns should display when executing perldoc, as perldoc's "ToMan" library defines several ways for determining line length depending on your environment.

Specifically it will use the MANWIDTH environment variable, or execute 'stty -a', or finally default to 73 characters - in that order.

Oh but wait, that strategy for determining line length? That's just for certain permutations of Linux. Other platforms defer to nroff directly for determining how many columns should be used.

Those other platforms may have implementations that correctly determine line length through nroff (as Quixadhal suggests) or they may have a hard coded value stashed way somewhere (as David W. suggests).

Unfortunately it appears this particular question does not have a one size fits all answer - at least based on my own experiences comparing FreeBSD and Linux.

One possibly trick that may be helpful: you can pass arguments directly to nroff through perldoc. So if your pod2usage happens to alias perldoc (sometimes does, sometimes doesn't?) then you can try passing an argument to nroff which maybe will force this to work for you:

```
pod2usage -n 'nroff -rLL=120n' sample.pm
```

This will only work if pod2usage is calling perldoc however, in some cases it's a completely separate implementation that won't accept a -n argument.